# How change local names for weeks in highcharts gantt

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I added local names in locale and change `xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.weeks`. But when I navigate to short time period, it shows `Week` (not `Неделя` as expected)

[image]

On longer time period it shows right `Week` name (as `Неделя`)
[image]

```
xAxis = {
    ...
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        hour: { list: ['%H:%M', '%H'] },
        day: { list: ['%A, %e. %B', '%a, %e. %b', '%E'] },
        week: { list: ['Неделя %W', 'Н%W', 'Н%W'] },
        month: { list: ['%B', '%b', '%o'] },
    },
}
```

highcharts version 9.3.3

How can I fix this bug?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behavior that is caused by setting dateTimeLabelFormats only for one xAxis. In case of your requirements, you need to set theese options for both axis:

```
xAxis:[{
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            hour: {
                list: ['%H:%M', '%H']
            },
            day: {
                list: ['%A, %e. %B', '%a, %e. %b', '%E']
            },
            week: {
                list: ['Неделя %W', 'W%W']
            },
            month: {
                list: ['%B', '%b', '%o']
            }
        },
},{
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            hour: {
                list: ['%H:%M', '%H']
            },
            day: {
                list: ['%A, %e. %B', '%a, %e. %b', '%E']
            },
            week: {
                list: ['Неделя %W', 'W%W']
            },
            month: {
                list: ['%B', '%b', '%o']
            }
        },
}],
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fwpusL5n/